# jQuery Datatables export to excelHtml5 HYPERLINK issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I have a Google script generated website using the jQuery plugin Datatables.
I'm having an issue with the export to Excel function of the Datatables plugin with Excel HYPERLINK.

I want a clickable hyperlink in my exported Excel file, so I format my link as follows in Javascript:

```js
=HYPERLINK("photourl";"Photo 1")
```

The Excel export is generated and the format is fine. However it shows the exact above snippet instead of a clickable link. When I select the cell and click once on the definition without making a change it automatically displays the clickable URL.

Is there anything I can do to turn it into a clickable link?

Comment: This may help. http://superuser.com/questions/836324/cells-not-updating-automatically/836325

Comment: I did not manage to correct the export from Datatables. I resolved my issue by taking all the data from the Datatable and writing it to a new Spreadsheet and then that spreadsheet I download as an Excel.

Answer (score 11):

> I hope my solution will help someone expand links in excel export to the already very
>   helpful library.

After hours of searching, I found a lot of people looking for a solution for links in Excel export here and in the forum at Datatables.

Main problem is that the default export only two different formats are considered. Numbers and inlinestring.
A link is neither a inlinestring nor a number, it is a function, witch need typ str.

In my search for a solution I find many helpful parts.

1. You have to adjust the export, the "customize" option is already provided for this. https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/excelTextBold.html
   In this example, all cells in column C are considered. We want to loop over all cells and find possible URLs there.
2. We want to replace the links with the formula. By default, it has the cell type inlinesting, this must be replaced by the type str and the formula used as a value.
   Thanks to Dzyann, who shows how it works.
   https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42097/can-you-export-a-table-and-format-a-cell-to-use-a-formula-using-orthogonal-data
3. To underline the link, it should be provided with the format [4].
   List of available formats: https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Built-in-styles

My solution that works for my requirement:

```
    // (1.) customize export
    customize: function( xlsx ) {

        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

        // Loop over all cells in sheet
        $('row c', sheet).each( function () {

            // if cell starts with http
            if ( $('is t', this).text().indexOf("http") === 0 ) {

                // (2.) change the type to `str` which is a formula
                $(this).attr('t', 'str');
                //append the formula
                $(this).append('<f>' + 'HYPERLINK("'+$('is t', this).text()+'","'+$('is t', this).text()+'")'+ '</f>');
                //remove the inlineStr
                $('is', this).remove();
                // (3.) underline
                $(this).attr( 's', '4' );
            }
        });
}
```

---

---

---

---

**UPDATE!! IE11**

After neirda found out that IE11 had problems adding a non-HTML object to $ (this), another solution had to be found. same basis: `<f> HYPERLINK`

File: buttons.html5.js

Line: 1098

Inserted a switch that creates the Celle differently for URL content. (As a formula, with HYPERLINK)

```
// Formula HYPERLINK for http-content, 
// is a URL if: a) started first char of cell content and 
//      b) without blanks
// s:4 use to unterline
if (    (row[i].indexOf("http") === 0) 
    &&
    (row[i].indexOf(" ") < 0 )  ) {

    cell = _createNode( rels, 'c', {
        attr: {
            t: 'str',
            r: cellId,
            s: 4
        },
        children:{
            row: _createNode( rels, 'f', { text: 'HYPERLINK(\"'+text+'\",\"'+text+'\")' } )
        }
    } );
} else {
    // String output - replace non standard characters for text output
    cell = _createNode( rels, 'c', {
        attr: {
            t: 'inlineStr',
            r: cellId
        },
        children:{
            row: _createNode( rels, 'is', {
                children: {
                    row: _createNode( rels, 't', {
                        text: text
                    } )
                }
            } )
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: I used your code successfully with Firefox, but it does not seem to work under IE 11, any idea why ?

Comment: Thank you for your test! Right, unfortunately it does not work in IE11. In Edge, Chrome Firefox, the links are exported successfully. No error message is displayed. The relevant steps are passed through the debug, no abnormalities ... Who could help us here?

Comment: Apparently it is the jQuery ".append()" which does not work as expected with IE 11, maybe there is an alternative technique but I don't know

Comment: in IE11 it seems to be a problem to create a non-HTML object this way. Also, this non-HTML object could not be appended by append.
So I had to do what I did not want to change the module "jQuery.Datatable buttons / js / buttons.html5.js"

Comment: Thanks a lot for this alternative solution, I confirm it works in IE 11 in my use case.

Comment: This worked for me too. But the cells with hyperlinks appear blank in protected view. They appear as soon as I Enable editing. Please let me know if you know a solution to this.

Comment: @Udhayha Karthik .Because hyperlink is a function. Functions are only executed after the button has been clicked. This is the same with calculating a sum. I think this is a security function of Excel.

Comment: Got it resolved by adding a <v> tag with the value in cell tag. Thanks anyway @SarahTrees

Comment: @UdhayhaKarthik  Is the link clickable by adding the `<v>`-solution? When yes, can you make please an example in a new answer?  If there was a new solution for the clickable links, that would probably be a better solution than per function hyperlink!

Comment: Solution not working for me. I even unable to change text of cell. When I use only $(this).append() method, generated excel is broken. And when I use both methods, $(this).append() and $('is', this).remove(); then existing text is being removed but new text is not inserted. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @WaqasAli I had the same issue; you need to also remove the v tag `$('v', this).remove();`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use an expression in the Excel Hyperlink Formula Format, e.g.:

='=HYPERLINK("https://[my website].com/' & [identifier] &'","' & [Friendly Excel Value] & '")'

Then you will find that within Excel it doesn't automatically recognise the formula by default. To force recognition the easiest way is to Replace (Ctrl+H) All equals '=' with equals '='.

The link should then work.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010062412.aspx

https://superuser.com/questions/448376/what-is-the-excel-hotkey-to-re-calculate-all-formula-in-sheet

Answer (score 1):

Export in Execl is very tough job without using any server side language,but you can write XML code to export data table in xls formate i have some working example 
please find the code and file [here](http://eportal.esparkbiz.com/asset/js/export_execl_js/jquery.battatech.excelexport.js)

this is jquery plugin

and I am writing sample code to export the file

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link  rel="stylesheet"  href="css/chintanTableDesign_1.css"/>
            <title></title>
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script src="http://eportal.esparkbiz.com/asset/js/export_execl_js/jquery.battatech.excelexport.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <table class="tableChintan" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="10" style="font-size: 25px;text-align: center">
                        ABC Pvt. ltd.
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <select id="type_account" name="type_account" onchange="GetFilter();">
                            <option value="ALL" >ALL</option>
                            <option value="AC" >AC</option>
                            <option value="CASH" >CASH</option>
                            <option value="PF" selected>PF</option>                        
                        </select>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a id="btnExport" href="javascript:void(0);"> EXPORT</a>
                    </th>
                </tr></table>
            <table class="tableChintan" width="100%" id="tblExport">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>BASIC</th>
                    <th>DA</th>
                    <th>HRA</th>
                    <th>TA</th>
                    <th>Sp Allownce</th>
                    <th>LEAVE ENCASH</th>
                    <th>abs_days</th>
                    <th>extra_days</th>
                    <th>PF EMP</th>
                    <th>PF COMP</th>
    <!--                <th>ESI EMP</th>
                    <th>ESI COMP</th>-->
                    <th>PT</th>
                    <th>TOTAL SAL CHEQUE</th>
                    <th>actual_sal </th>
                    <th>actual_sal WP</th>
                    <th>NA</th>
                    <th></th>

                </tr>
               </tr></table>       
     </table>
        </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnExport").click(function () {
                $("#tblExport").btechco_excelexport({
                    containerid: "tblExport"
                    , datatype: $datatype.Table
                });
            });

        });
</script>
```

PLease don't forgot to include your jquery.min.js

please do try if you want to forcefully rename file then let me know I have another jquery plugin for same

Enjoy !!!!!!!!!!!!