# jQuery Datatables how to make Hyper link

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

I am exporting an excel file with jQuery Datatables but it does not make Hyper link in the excel file. i've tried many solutions but no one worked for me.

i found [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/excelCellShading.html) example where we can use `customize` property to do formatting with our cell. i wanted to run excel formula which is 
`return '==HYPERLINK("http://example.microsoft.com/report/budget report.xlsx", "Click for report")';` some thing like this but it export the formula as it is infested of rendering .

i found a attributes [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx#odc_xmlss_howto) that can be use in datatables `customize` property .

previously i was doing it like this

```js
   "columnDefs": [
             {
                 "data": "download_link",
                 "render":  function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                     return '==HYPERLINK("http://example.microsoft.com/report/budget report.xlsx", "Click for report")';
                 },
                 "targets": [26,27,28]
             }
         ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stand before the same problem. I found so many unanswered questions. Here is my solution.

[jQuery Datatables export to excelHtml5 HYPERLINK issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243616/jquery-datatables-export-to-excelhtml5-hyperlink-issue/49146977#49146977)

Answer (score 1):

Per [Datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5),

> At this time, although an XLSX file is created, data formatting,
>   colours, etc are not retained. Only the raw data from the table is
>   included in the exported file. For complete control over the generated
>   file, a custom button could be constructed using the SheetJS library.

So use
https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx and a [custom button](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfPage.html)

Might be quite a bit of work, but seems like it is possible.